# Pandas Unable to extract/filter only rows from pandas DF?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have below csv file reading as df in pands

```
table       entity_name  node_name  src_name      table_col_name    look_up_indicator   type       keys
gw_policy   account       ns0       fullname      insured_name        N                 attribute   NA
gw_policy   polocy        ns1       agent_name    agent               N                 attribute   NA
gw_policy   account       ns2       phone_num     agent_phone         N                 attribute   NA
```

i reading the csv in to pandas and extracting the specific column value

Here in the case i extracting only 'agent' rows from 'table_col_name'

```
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
policy=data.loc[data['table_col_name']=='agent', ['node_name', 'src_name']]
print(policy)
```

it will print the data frame as

```
node_name  src_name
ns1        agent_name
```

Now i want to iterate througn the column loop

```
column_name=['insured_name', 'agent', 'agent_phone']

for value in column_name:
    policy=data.loc[data['table_col_name']==value, ['node_name', 'src_name']]
    print("Looped attribute",policy)
```

```
#Output
Looped attribute           node_name  src_name
table                        
gw_policy       ns0  fullname


Looped attribute           node_name    src_name
table                          
gw_policy       ns1  agent_name

Looped attribute           node_name    src_name
table                          
gw_policy       ns2  phone_num
```

#Expected:
i just need to get only the the row values as such

```
ns0  fullname

ns1  agent_name

ns2  phone_num
```

Appreciate if anybody can help on this?

Thanks

Comment: For me workign perfectly, is not overwritten variable `data` to some string?

Comment: HI @jezrael can you explain please  how i supposed to do?

Comment: post all code, because here hard to know what is problem.

Comment: Hi @jezrael.. sorry it was by mistake, that code for the question was working fine.. i wrongly placed the variable.. by the way, i am facing other issue in extracting the required values from the df based on some condition.. i have updated my question.. can you please look in to it?

Comment: Do you need `data.loc[data['table_col_name']==value, ['node_name', 'src_name']].tolist()` ?

Comment: yea.. that also fine @jezrael.. but only include 'ns0  fullname' as such..not other parameter..

Comment: Unfortunately not understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226345/discussion-between-cloud-hari-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from @ jezrael . The approach is to make the list out of the filter

```
data.loc[data['table_col_name']==value, ['node_name', 'src_name']].iloc[0].tolist()
```

Thanks